# Regex Markdown Header

Tags: ruby, regex, markdown

I'm trying to create a regular (ruby) expression which checks for multiple conditions. I use this regex to replace the content of my object. My regex is close to finished, except two problems I'm facing with regard to markdown.

First of, headers are giving me trouble. For example, I don't want to replace the word "Hi" for "Hello" if "Hi" is in a header.

```
Hi John <== # should not change
==================
```

> Text: Hi, how are you? <== # Should be: Hello, how are you? after substitution

Or:

```
#### Hi Peter <== # should not change
```

> Text: Hi, how are you? <== # Should be: Hello, how are you? after substitution

**Question**: How can I escape markdown headers within my regex? I've tried negative lookbehind and lookahead assertions, but to no avail.

My second problem should be quite easy, but somehow I'm struggling. If words are Italic "*hi*" I want to find and replace them, without changing the underscores. I can find the word with this regex:

```
\b[_]*hi[_]*\b
```

**Question 2**: But if I would replace it, I would also change the underscores. Is there a way to only detect the word itself and replace it, while still using word boundaries?

**Code Example**

```
@website.autolinks.all.each do |autolink|
  autolink.name #for example returns "Iphone5"
  autolink.url  #for example returns "http://www.apple.com"

  regex = /\b(?<!##\s)(?<![\d.\[])([_]*)#{autolink.name}([_]*)(?![\d'"<\/a>])\b/

  if @permalink.blog_entry.content.match(regex)
    @permalink.blog_entry.content.gsub!(regex, "[#{autolink.name}](#  {autolink.url})")  
  end
end
```

Example text

```
Iphone5 
==============
```

> Iphone5 is the best mobile phone there is, even though the people at Samsung probably think, or perhaps only hope that their Samsung Galaxy S3 is better.

```
#### Samsung Galaxy S3?
```

> Yes, that's the name of the newest Samsung phone.

This will result in a text with HTML tags, but when I use my regex my content uses Markdown syntax (used before the markdown converter).

Comment: is there something in the header at all, that you want to change?

Comment: No, I only want to replace certain words in my text with links. Headers should remain untouched. I tried adding (?<![^##+\s]) to skip lines that start with "##+ " but it doesn't check for the combination of characters.

Comment: Are you rendering this document to HTML — if so, how about doing the find-and-replace on the HTML? You can easily run it on all paragraph elements, which will exclude headers.

Comment: I'm using Markdown with MarkitUp. In my view it is rendered to HTML. However, I'm doing the find-and-replace in my show action before actually rendering the show page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution:

```
regex = /(?<!##\s)(?<![\d.\[a-z])#{autolink.name}(?![\d'"a-z<\/a>])(?!.*\n(==|--))/i

    if @permalink.blog_entry.content.match(regex) 
      @permalink.blog_entry.content.gsub!(regex, "[\\0](#{autolink.url})")
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Regexes work best when they do one clear thing.  If you have multiple conditions, your code should usually reflect that by dividing the processing into steps.

In this case, you have two clear steps:

1. Use a simple regex or other logic to skip over the header portion of the message.
2. Once you know you are in the content, use another regex to process the content.

Comment: But what if you have a text like this: "HEADER Content SUBHEADER Content" within the same object.content. In theory, headers can arise everywhere within the content. They are not necessarily in a different attribute such as object.title.

Comment: @PeterdeRidder, you can still use one regex to determine what is not a header, then another regex to process the content portions.  If you have questions about the specifics of implementing that, update your question with a clearer example of what your data looks like, as well as a sample of the code you are using.